# Ruby CSV | How to skip few columns while reading CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activerecord-import

I am bulk importing data from a CSV file into database using [Active record Import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). But I want to skip few CSV columns when importing.

For example, my xaa.csv has headers like name, author, author_id, rating.
While importing, I want to skip the 'author_id' column values and import all the other columns.

```
books = CSV.read("/public/xaa.csv") //What more should I do here to skip the 3rd column
columns = [:name, :author, :rating]
Book.import columns, books, :validate => false
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the headers option.  Read the headers and then you can selectively import each row based on the column.  I do that all the time

Comment: try this `columns = [:name, :author, nil, :rating]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
books = []

CSV.foreach('/public/xaa.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  books << [row['name'], row['author'], row['rating']]
end

columns = [:name, :author, :rating]
Book.import(columns, books, validate: false)
```

Comment: This is functionally no different than the original code. For the "how to skip 3rd column" requirement, you need to set row['rating'] = nil, or replace nil in the 3rd position in the books << line

Comment: Thankyou @vegetaras.

Answer (score 2):

```
books = CSV.readlines(path, headers:true).map{|row| row.values_at('name','rating') }
```

vegetaras's version is slightly more memory efficient.